# Was the plural future imperative ever used?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, verbs, conjugation

In Latin today, we ran across the word "*esto*", which our teacher told us is the future singular imperative of "sum, esse". When I half-jokingly asked what the plural was, he thought for a few seconds and stated that, while it probably exists, he'd never seen it, but if he had to guess, he'd say "estote".

After an admittedly brief search, seeing as I don't really know where to look, I can't find "estote" anywhere. However, [Victionarium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/estote#Latin), and [William Whitaker's Words](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=estote) confirm it exists. Where does it appear? Or do we just add -te to create the plural like any other infinitive and assume that it's correct?

*NB: While I'd prefer examples in Classical Latin, usage in any Latin is fine.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [Perseus Project](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/), I see many occurrences of [estote](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=la&page=1&phrase=&documents=&all_words=estote&exclude_words=&any_words=); a disproportionate number of them appear to be in St. Jerome's Latin Vulgate. Here are two examples:

[1 Maccabees 2:50, Latin Vulgate](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0060%3Abook%3D1%20Maccabees%3Achapter%3D2%3Averse%3D50)

> nunc ergo o filii aemulatores estote legis et date animas vestras pro testamento patrum
>
> Now therefore, O (my) sons, be zealots of the law...

[1 Corinthians 4:16](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0060%3Abook%3D1%20Corinthians%3Achapter%3D4%3Averse%3D16)

> rogo ergo vos imitatores mei estote
>
> I ask you: be imitators of me.

---

For a use in the Classical period, see [this](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:2008.01.0564:book=4:chapter=6&highlight=estote) from [Seneca the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seneca_the_Elder)(54 BC – c. 39 AD):

> Quid fletis, pueri? securi estote;
>
> Boys, why do you cry? Be free from care!

---

So, it could be that it's a rare construction, but for whatever reason, Jerome uses it a number of times. It's worth noting that again according to the Perseus project, [*estote*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=estote&la=la&can=estote0&prior=et) can also come from *edo*, so those search results are an upper bound on the number of occurrences (at least twice as the plural future imperative of *esse*).

Comment: Jerome's estote is translating the Greek γίνεσθε (ginesthe), which indeed is the 2nd person plural imperative of γίγνομαι (gignomai).

Answer (score 7):

**Estōte** occurs five times in *Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata* by Hans Henning Ørberg. This textbook, written in the 20th century, teaches elementary conversational classical Latin by example. The story is set in about 150 A.D., is limited to basic language, and often presents simplified versions of excerpts from classical works, sometimes quoting directly when the language is basic enough. It's my understanding that Ørberg took historical accuracy very seriously in *LLPSI*. I take Ørberg's use of **estōte** to mean that it's *basic* Latin that everyone should feel comfortable with.

Here are three examples.

p. 209, illustrating *gerundium*:

> Industriī **estōte** in scrīb*endō,* discipulī!

p. 282, illustrating the plural *imperātīvus futūrī*:

> Magister: "Posthāc bonī discipulī **estōte**, puerī! Semper mihi pār*ētōte!* Dīligenter aud*ītōte!* Pulchrē recit*ātōte* et rēctē scrīb*itōte!"*

p. 225–226, quoting Matthew 14:26–27:

> Discipulī autem videntēs eum super mare ambulantem turbātī sunt dīcentēs: "Phantasma est!" et prae timōre clāmāvērunt. Statimque Iēsūs locūtus est eīs dīcēns: "Cōnstantēs **estōte**! Ego sum. Nōlīte timēre!"

I think this is from a version of *Matthaeus* in use in 150 A.D.; see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=8odbAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PR11&ots=HvCtsA8LXH&dq=old%20latin%20book%20matthew&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q&f=false) for a similar one. Jerome's version has *habete fiduciam* rather than *constantes estote.* However, a quick Google search suggests that *constantes estote* and similar are common expressions. *Constantes estote et videbitis auxilium Domini super vos, Estote fortes in bello,* etc.

Quārē dubitāstī? :)

Comment: While *estote* is indeed used in Latin, and your examples aren't wrong *per se*, I feel that it's cheating a bit to use a textbook for examples answering if the future imperative was used. Moreover, the Matthew example is a translation, so it too isn't best as an example, although in this case it's seems a good example of a vulgar translation since neither *constantes estote* or *habete fiduciam* translate θαρσεῖτε well, but Jerome's feels more Classical (disclaimer: I haven't done the research on either phrase).

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I wouldn't call this a definitive answer, but it's suggestive indirect evidence. It's my understanding that Ørberg took historical accuracy very seriously in LLPSI; I'm just going on Ørberg's authority.

Answer (score 6):

Not only was *estote* used, but also the third person plural future imperative *sunto*.
This is not limited to *esse*; a quick search produced examples for *facere* as well (*facito*, *facitote*, *faciunto*).

Besides using a specialized search tool like James Kingsbery mentions, you can also use Google.
Knowing that [The Latin Library](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/) contains a lot of relevant texts, searching for "site:thelatinlibrary.com estote" is a simple way to find examples.

I will leave finding examples of the mentioned forms to you because I want to encourage you to play with such search tools.
You may also want to check out [our list of Latin text corpora and related tools](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1854/79).