# Where I can find Old Latin word list?

Tags: resource-request, old-latin

Where I can find a list of Old Latin words where they differ from Classical Latin? Are words like *oinos* and *comoinis* attested, or they are reconstructions?

Comment: Well, if you're good with python.  There is a corpus that has the works divided into six or seven different eras.  See here: https://legacy.cltk.org/en/latest/latin.html

Comment: It's not easy however, so if you're able to use python let me know and i'll give more details

Comment: This is really two questions built into one. But this second question is already answered [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/where-to-find-an-online-latin-text-corpus-and-what-can-i-do-with-it?rq=1), so I'm going to roll back to your original question and open it back up. As always, adding more details about what you're looking for will yield better results. Feel free to come to chat and ping me (@cmw or any other mod that's on) if you have further questions.